# How do I display a decimal value to 2 decimal places?

Tags: c#, .net, format, decimal

When displaying the value of a decimal currently with `.ToString()`, it's accurate to like 15 decimal places, and since I'm using it to represent dollars and cents, I only want the output to be 2 decimal places.

Do I use a variation of `.ToString()` for this?

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58733847/2093077) is a brief example of the different options for formatting floating point values (alignment, number of digits, group separators, exponential, percent, currency, etc.).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using String Format to show decimal up to 2 places or simple integer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6951335/using-string-format-to-show-decimal-up-to-2-places-or-simple-integer)

Answer (score 1183, accepted):

```
decimalVar.ToString("#.##"); // returns ".5" when decimalVar == 0.5m
```

or

```
decimalVar.ToString("0.##"); // returns "0.5"  when decimalVar == 0.5m
```

or

```
decimalVar.ToString("0.00"); // returns "0.50"  when decimalVar == 0.5m
```

Comment: the problem here is when we have 0.00; it returns an empty string.

Comment: Then you could do decimalVar.ToString ("0.##").
You can also use 0.00 as the formatting string.

Comment: @MikeCole I don't think you can perform truncation with just formatting alone -- the only way I know is to pass it into Math.Floor first, so something like (Math.Floor(decimalVar * 100M) / 100M).ToString("0.00") should work (and if you're using doubles and not decimals use 100D instead of 100M, of course).

Comment: With this solution, you won't have the culture formatting that one would expect when reading numbers. For this you should use ToString("N2"), or ToString("N").

Comment: This is a very misleading answer. This just creates a new string, Yet the number value remains unchanged. This creates havoc anywhere else this number is consumed. It is a seroius issu not be able to downgrade type decimal to some number of decimal places.

Comment: @Hill `Decimal` and `Double` type `ToString` method accepts argument for formatting. Try converting your value to Decimal/Double first.

Comment: @f470071 Decimals are value types and as such are never "modified". Regardless, ToString() has never been expected to modify the contents of whatever it is called on.

Comment: Works ok for decimals. If its an integer number then "#.##" will ignore the decimal places. However "{0:#,##0.00}" will work for both decimal and integer numbers.

Comment: @Hill You may get that error with nullable type. Try yourNumber.Value.ToString(0.##) to solve your problem

Comment: The solution below is better, as it deals with it as a decimal and returns decimal

Comment: This one helped me retain the trailing decimal places. As long as you convert back to Decimal type like this: Convert.ToDecimal(costInDecimal.ToString("0.00"));

Answer (score 691):

I know this is an old question, but I was surprised to see that no one seemed to post an answer that;

1. Didn't use bankers rounding
2. Keeps the value as a decimal.

This is what I would use:

```
decimal.Round(yourValue, 2, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero);
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9s0xa85y.aspx

Comment: ToString or string.Format don't use bankers rounding: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8.aspx#sectionToggle1

Comment: @MatthijsWessels I know... but it doesn't keep the value as a decimal either.

Comment: This is a better way to truly represent two decimal places as it will not drop trailing zeros.

Answer (score 458):

```
decimalVar.ToString("F");
```

This will:

- Round off to 2 decimal places *eg.* `23.456` → `23.46`
- Ensure that there
  are always 2 decimal places *eg.* `23` → `23.00`; `12.5` → `12.50`

Ideal for displaying currency.

Check out the documentation on [ToString("F")](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#FFormatString) (thanks to Jon Schneider).

Comment: This works fine when only has 1 decimal; .ToString("#.##") fails. This answer is much better

Comment: Wouldn't it round 23.456 => 23.46 ?

Comment: Documentation on what the "F" means here, and how it works: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#FFormatString

Comment: Why not .ToString("N") instead of "F"?  It's my understanding they'll both work for the needs of this question, but N will also put commas in for numbers in the thousands.

Comment: Note: The `.` might be replaced with `,` based on the culture. You should pass along `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` as the second argument to disable this.

Comment: What's the difference between "F" and "0.00"?

Answer (score 122):

If you just need this for display use string.Format

```
String.Format("{0:0.00}", 123.4567m);      // "123.46"
```

http://www.csharp-examples.net/string-format-double/

The "m" is a decimal suffix. About the decimal suffix:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/364x0z75.aspx

Comment: Techinically, for a decimal, it would be 123.4567m, yes?  Without the "m" suffix, it's a double

Comment: or shortcut $"{value:0.00}"

Answer (score 63):

If you want it formatted with commas as well as a decimal point (but no currency symbol), such as 3,456,789.12...

```
decimalVar.ToString("n2");
```

Comment: Better answer as the question was about outputting on a page, and the number formatting is important for big numbers. Also, "n*" takes into account the current culture, so it could be "3.456.789,12", "3 456 789,12", etc.

Answer (score 59):

Given **decimal d=12.345;** the expressions **d.ToString("C")** or **String.Format("{0:C}", d)** yield **$12.35** - note that the current culture's currency settings including the symbol are used.

Note that ["C"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#CFormatString) uses number of digits from current culture. You can always override default to force necessary precision with `C{Precision specifier}` like `String.Format("{0:C2}", 5.123d)`.

Comment: @Slick86 - the currenty sign

Answer (score 45):

There's a very important characteristic of `Decimal` that isn't obvious:

> A `Decimal` 'knows' how many decimal places it has based upon where it came from

The following may be unexpected :

```
Decimal.Parse("25").ToString()          =>   "25"
Decimal.Parse("25.").ToString()         =>   "25"
Decimal.Parse("25.0").ToString()        =>   "25.0"
Decimal.Parse("25.0000").ToString()     =>   "25.0000"

25m.ToString()                          =>   "25"
25.000m.ToString()                      =>   "25.000"
```

Doing the same operations with `Double` will result in zero decimal places (`"25"`) for all of the above examples.

If you want a decimal to 2 decimal places there's a high likelihood it's because it's currency in which case this is probably fine for 95% of the time:

```
Decimal.Parse("25.0").ToString("c")     =>   "$25.00"
```

Or in XAML you would use `{Binding Price, StringFormat=c}`

One case I ran into where I needed a decimal AS a decimal was when sending XML to Amazon's webservice. The service was complaining because a Decimal value (originally from SQL Server) was being sent as `25.1200` and rejected, (`25.12` was the expected format).

All I needed to do was `Decimal.Round(...)` with 2 decimal places to fix the problem regardless of the source of the value.

```
 // generated code by XSD.exe
 StandardPrice = new OverrideCurrencyAmount()
 {
       TypedValue = Decimal.Round(product.StandardPrice, 2),
       currency = "USD"
 }
```

`TypedValue` is of type `Decimal` so I couldn't just do `ToString("N2")` and needed to round it and keep it as a `decimal`.

Comment: +1 this is a great answer. When you say that System.Decimal "knows how many decimal places is has" - the term is that System.Decimal is not **self-normalizing** as the other floating point types are. Another useful property of System.Decimal is that the result of math operations always have the highest number of decimal places from the input arguments ie. *1.0m + 2.000m = 3.000m*. You can use this fact to force a decimal with no decimal places to 2 decimal places simply by multiplying it by 1.00m eg. *10m * 1.00m = 10.00m*.

Comment: MattDavey's is incorrect, the decimal precision is added.  (1.0m * 1.00m).ToString() = "1.000"

Comment: It is very, very useful to know that "A decimal 'knows' how many decimal places it has based upon where it came from."  Thanks a lot!

Comment: appreciate your answer and explanation!

Answer (score 24):

Here is a little Linqpad program to show different formats:

```
void Main()
{
    FormatDecimal(2345.94742M);
    FormatDecimal(43M);
    FormatDecimal(0M);
    FormatDecimal(0.007M);
}

public void FormatDecimal(decimal val)
{
    Console.WriteLine("ToString: {0}", val);
    Console.WriteLine("c: {0:c}", val);
    Console.WriteLine("0.00: {0:0.00}", val);
    Console.WriteLine("0.##: {0:0.##}", val);
    Console.WriteLine("===================");
}
```

Here are the results:

```
ToString: 2345.94742
c: $2,345.95
0.00: 2345.95
0.##: 2345.95
===================
ToString: 43
c: $43.00
0.00: 43.00
0.##: 43
===================
ToString: 0
c: $0.00
0.00: 0.00
0.##: 0
===================
ToString: 0.007
c: $0.01
0.00: 0.01
0.##: 0.01
===================
```

Answer (score 16):

[Math.Round Method (Decimal, Int32)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zy06z30k.aspx)

Comment: doesn't that use banker's rounding?

Comment: This is the best way, because the value doesnt convert to a string and you can still performing math operations

Comment: @Danimal: You can supply a third argument to change the rounding type

Answer (score 16):

Very rarely would you want an empty string if the value is 0.

```
decimal test = 5.00;
test.ToString("0.00");  //"5.00"
decimal? test2 = 5.05;
test2.ToString("0.00");  //"5.05"
decimal? test3 = 0;
test3.ToString("0.00");  //"0.00"
```

The top rated answer is incorrect and has wasted 10 minutes of (most) people's time.

Comment: basically 
`"#"` means digit of number (if necessary) (without padding if not needed)
`"0"` means digit of number (no mater what) (padded with zeros if not available)

Answer (score 14):

[Mike M.'s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5724542) was perfect for me on .NET, but .NET Core doesn't have a `decimal.Round` method at the time of writing.

In .NET Core, I had to use:

```
decimal roundedValue = Math.Round(rawNumber, 2, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero);
```

A hacky method, including conversion to string, is:

```
public string FormatTo2Dp(decimal myNumber)
{
    // Use schoolboy rounding, not bankers.
    myNumber = Math.Round(myNumber, 2, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero);

    return string.Format("{0:0.00}", myNumber);
}
```

Answer (score 10):

None of these did exactly what I needed, to force **2 d.p.** and round up as `0.005 -> 0.01`

Forcing 2 d.p. requires increasing the precision by 2 d.p. to ensure we have at least 2 d.p.

then rounding to ensure we do not have more than 2 d.p.

```
Math.Round(exactResult * 1.00m, 2, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero)

6.665m.ToString() -> "6.67"

6.6m.ToString() -> "6.60"
```

Answer (score 10):

The top-rated answer describes a method for formatting the *string representation* of the decimal value, and it works.

However, if you actually want to change the precision saved to the actual value, you need to write something like the following:

```
public static class PrecisionHelper
{
    public static decimal TwoDecimalPlaces(this decimal value)
    {
        // These first lines eliminate all digits past two places.
        var timesHundred = (int) (value * 100);
        var removeZeroes = timesHundred / 100m;

        // In this implementation, I don't want to alter the underlying
        // value.  As such, if it needs greater precision to stay unaltered,
        // I return it.
        if (removeZeroes != value)
            return value;

        // Addition and subtraction can reliably change precision.  
        // For two decimal values A and B, (A + B) will have at least as 
        // many digits past the decimal point as A or B.
        return removeZeroes + 0.01m - 0.01m;
    }
}
```

An example unit test:

```
[Test]
public void PrecisionExampleUnitTest()
{
    decimal a = 500m;
    decimal b = 99.99m;
    decimal c = 123.4m;
    decimal d = 10101.1000000m;
    decimal e = 908.7650m

    Assert.That(a.TwoDecimalPlaces().ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture),
        Is.EqualTo("500.00"));

    Assert.That(b.TwoDecimalPlaces().ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture),
        Is.EqualTo("99.99"));

    Assert.That(c.TwoDecimalPlaces().ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture),
        Is.EqualTo("123.40"));

    Assert.That(d.TwoDecimalPlaces().ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture),
        Is.EqualTo("10101.10"));

    // In this particular implementation, values that can't be expressed in
    // two decimal places are unaltered, so this remains as-is.
    Assert.That(e.TwoDecimalPlaces().ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture),
        Is.EqualTo("908.7650"));
}
```

Answer (score 8):

You can use system.globalization to format a number in any required format.

**For example:**

```
system.globalization.cultureinfo ci = new system.globalization.cultureinfo("en-ca");
```

If you have a `decimal d = 1.2300000` and you need to trim it to 2 decimal places then it can be printed like this `d.Tostring("F2",ci);` where F2 is string formating to 2 decimal places and ci is the locale or cultureinfo.

for more info check this link
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx

Comment: +1 but - the CultureInfo object would only affect the unicode character used to denote the decimal place. eg. fr-FR would use a comma instead of a period. It's not related to the number of decimal places rendered.

Answer (score 7):

The most applicable solution is

```
decimalVar.ToString("#.##");
```

Comment: For some it might be, for others not necessarily...

Comment: Exactly,  this is the best answer, you don't need decimal ".00" postfixes when the number is an int

Answer (score 6):

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

This link explains in detail how you can handle your problem and what you can do if you want to learn more. For simplicity purposes, what you want to do is

```
double whateverYouWantToChange = whateverYouWantToChange.ToString("F2");
```

if you want this for a currency, you can make it easier by typing "C2" instead of "F2"

Answer (score 4):

```
Double Amount = 0;
string amount;
amount=string.Format("{0:F2}", Decimal.Parse(Amount.ToString()));
```

Answer (score 4):

If you need to keep only 2 decimal places (i.e. cut off all the rest of decimal digits):

```
decimal val = 3.14789m;
decimal result = Math.Floor(val * 100) / 100; // result = 3.14
```

If you need to keep only 3 decimal places:

```
decimal val = 3.14789m;
decimal result = Math.Floor(val * 1000) / 1000; // result = 3.147
```

Answer (score 1):

```
        var arr = new List<int>() { -4, 3, -9, 0, 4, 1 };
        decimal result1 = arr.Where(p => p > 0).Count();
        var responseResult1 = result1 / arr.Count();
        decimal result2 = arr.Where(p => p < 0).Count();
        var responseResult2 = result2 / arr.Count();
        decimal result3 = arr.Where(p => p == 0).Count();
        var responseResult3 = result3 / arr.Count();
        Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0:#,0.000}", responseResult1));
        Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0:#,0.0000}", responseResult2));
        Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0:#,0.00000}", responseResult3));
```

you can put as many 0 as you want.