# how to convert decimal points?

Tags: c#, function, rounding

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [c# - How do I round a decimal value to 2 decimal places (for output on a page)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/164926/c-sharp-how-do-i-round-a-decimal-value-to-2-decimal-places-for-output-on-a-pa)

i have value of 1.564 and 1.565 i need round this value to 1.56 and 1.56,which function suitable for this in c#.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To remove the less significant digits (1.348 -> 1.34):

```
Math.Floor(number * 100) / 100;
```

To round the number to two decimals:

```
Math.Round(number, 2);
```

To represent it as a string, for display:

```
number.ToString("#.00");
```

Comment: for this 1.5674 and 1.5675 how can i

Comment: for this 1.5674 and 1.5675 how can i convert this to 1.567 & 1.567

Comment: the same with `1000`, `3` and `#.000`. This assumes you need a **fixed number of decimals**. Do you need a function that removes the last digit? That is weird, isn't it?

Answer (score 5):

do a multiply by 100 followed by a floor and followed by a divide by hundred. I am sure that there is a better way of doing it though

```
Math.floor(n*100)/100
```

Comment: On C# that's `Floor`, by the way.