# Format to two decimal places

Tags: c#

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [c# - How do I round a decimal value to 2 decimal places (for output on a page)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/164926/c-sharp-how-do-i-round-a-decimal-value-to-2-decimal-places-for-output-on-a-pa)

I have a number

```
long n = 32432432423;
```

I want to divide this by 1450 and print on a console with 2 decimal places (rounded)

How can I do it?

```
COnsole.WriteLine(????);
```

Answer (score 52, accepted):

```
Console.WriteLine("{0:N2}", ((double)n) / 1450);
```

Answer (score 8):

```
Console.WriteLine("{0:0.00}", 32432432423 / 1450.0);
```

Comment: this rounds automatically, so better answer than @Pranay's

Answer (score 8):

make use of [Math.Round](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3s2d3xkk.aspx)

```
Console.WriteLine( Math.Round(Convert.ToDecimal(32432432423 / 1450.0), 2));
```

Result: `22367194.77`