# How to check input double value contain how many digits?

Tags: c#, algorithm

I need a double value to contain 2 digits after ".", such as 2.15, 20.15. If the input value is 3.125, then it should print an error message.

My code is:

```
    private static bool isTwoDigits(double num)
    {
        return (num - Math.Floor(num)).ToString().Length <= 4;
    }
```

If you input 2.15, then it will be 2.15 -2 = 0.15 <= 4 - which works. But when I change `num` to 20.15 it doesn't, because `(num - Math.Floor(num))` here will return `0.14999999999`.

Any other good ideas?

Comment: This has been asked before

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3359916/format-to-two-decimal-places

Comment: This has been asked before.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3359916/format-to-two-decimal-places

Comment: @user430788: this is not exactly the same question. The question here is not how to round the number, but how to assert the number of decimal places in a given number.

Comment: @user430788 it looks like it is not the same

Comment: OH, fair enough.

Then yeah, regexp it and count the length of whats after the .

Comment: @user430788, thanks anyway though that not what i am looking for !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the nature of binary floating points number. Just like 1/3 can't be exactly written out as a finite decimal number, 0.1 can't be exactly represented by a finite binary expansion.

So depending on what you are trying to achieve exactly, you could:

1. If you are validating some string input (e.g. a textbox), you can process the information at the string level, e.g. with a RegEx.
2. You can store your numbers in the `decimal` datatype, which can store decimal values exactly.
3. You can do your computation on a `double` but you have to give yourself a tolerance. If you expect only 2 digits of precision, you can do something like `Math.Abs(x - Math.Round(x, 2)) < 0.00000001)`. The definition of this tolerance margin depends on your use case.

Answer (score 0):

If you're really worried about the number of decimal places, on a base-10 number, use `decimal` instead of `double`.

the `decimal` is for calculating financial calculations, and the reason it's called `decimal` in the first place is so that it can better handle base-10 calculations such as dollars and cents.

And you can also check if the number is 2 digits a bit more simply.

```
return num % 0.01m == 0.0m;
```

Comment: I use your solution "return num % 0.01 == 0;" but it doesn't work !

Comment: it works only _on the decimal datatype._ That's what the `m` suffix on constants means.

Answer (score 0):

SO as has already been said, you can use regexp to ensure the entire format is correct.

But if you know there will only be 1 decimal because its already a number you can also just use String.IndexOf

eg

```
double foo = ....  ;
string fooString = foo.ToString();
if (fooString.Length - fooString.IndexOf(".") != 3)  => error.
```

(Its 3 because Length is max index + 1 )