# How to make it, so there are only 3 or 4 number after a comma in C#?

Tags: c#, oop

I am new in programming completely. This is my first lesson. I know 0%. We are trying OOP Windows Form app. SO how can I make it so there is only 3/4 numbers after the comma.
**The Code:**

```
double TgG(double x)
{
    return Math.Tan(x*Math.PI/180);
} //TanG

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    double x, y;
    x= double.Parse(textBox1.Text);
    y = TgG(x);
    label2.Text = y.ToString();
} //TanG(x) button click
```

Comment: Taker a look at the documentation for the double.ToString() method you use. You should find an overload there for that method to allow formatting the output.

Comment: See also this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3602392/round-double-to-two-decimal-places

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C# you choose the format when you dispaly a value or convert it to a string. To do that use [this overload of `ToString`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.double.tostring?view=net-6.0#system-double-tostring(system-string)) with the following format:

```
// Format as a numeric value with 3 decimal places.
label2.Text = y.ToString("N3");
```

The documentation linked above gives several other built-in formats, and you can specify custom formats as well.

Answer (score 1):

Use the .Round() method. Here's an example of using it:

```
    //Rounding 1.678 to 2 decimal places
    Math.Round(1.678, 2); //1.68
```