# How to round and format a decimal correctly?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, sql-server, vb.net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [c# - How do I round a decimal value to 2 decimal places (for output on a page)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/164926/c-sharp-how-do-i-round-a-decimal-value-to-2-decimal-places-for-output-on-a-pa)

I'm trying to get my decimals to display with four decimal places.  The DB rounds my number to 4 decimal places, but it returns the number with trailing 0s (due to the decimal precision of the field), so something like 9.45670000. Then, when I do this:

```
string.Format("{0:#,#.####}", decimalValue);
```

The output I get on the page is 9.4567, which is what I want.

However, if the number returned from DB is 9.45600000, the output after doing the format is 9.456

But what I need to display is 9.4560

How do I format my decimal, so that the number of decimal places is always four?

UPDATE: Also, is it possible to use a variable (instead of .0000) if I wanted the number of decimal places to be determined dynamically?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
string.Format("{0:N4}",decimalValue);
```

[Standard Numeric Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k(v=VS.100).aspx)

[Custom Numeric Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8.aspx)

To set the precision dynamically you can do the following:

```
double value = 9.4560000;
int precision = 4;
string format = String.Format("{{0:N{0}}}",precision);
string valuestring = String.Format(format, value);
```

Comment: Based on comments below, commas are important too you.  This format string adds them correctly.  Also, I've edited my response to provide a link to standard numeric format strings for future reference.

Answer (score 1):

```
string.Format({0:#,#0.0000}, decimalValue);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [String.Format](http://www.csharp-examples.net/string-format-double/) -

```
    decimal d =123.47
    string specifier="{0:0,0.0000}"; // You need to get specifier dynamically here..
    String.Format(specifier, d);      // "123.4700"
```

Comment: I need the commas for large numbers though...

Comment: Is it possible to use a variable (instead of .0000) if I wanted the number of decimal places to be determined dynamically?

Comment: @Prabhu I've edited my answer to provide an example of how to do this

Comment: yea..check my response and this - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fzeeb5cd.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
string.Format("{0:#,###.0000}", 9.45600000);
```

Adding the zeroes in the format forces a zero to be output if there is not a digit to put there.

To add the zeroes with the number of zeroes driven programmatically you could do this:

```
  int x = 5;
  string fmt = "{0:#,###." + new string('0', x) + "}";
  string.Format(fmt, 9.456000000);
```

Comment: Is it possible to use a variable (instead of .0000) if I wanted the number of decimal places to be determined dynamically?

Comment: @theChrisKent's answer is better than mine.  I had forgotten about the precision specifier.