# Formatting a float to 2 decimal places

Tags: c#, variables, floating-point, decimal

I am currently building a sales module for a clients website. So far I have got the sale price to calculate perfectly but where I have come stuck is formatting the output to 2 decimal places.

I am currently calling this in a variable so that I can data bind the results to a listview.

```
Sale = float.Parse(((x.Sale_Price - (x.Sale_Price * (x.Discount_Price / 100))).ToString())),
```

Can anyone show me how to format the output to 2 decimal places?? Many Thanks!

Comment: Check this i am not sure but might be it will work ToString ("#.##");

Answer (score 577, accepted):

You can pass the format in to the `ToString` method, e.g.:

```
myFloatVariable.ToString("0.00"); //2dp Number

myFloatVariable.ToString("n2"); // 2dp Number

myFloatVariable.ToString("c2"); // 2dp currency
```

[Standard Number Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx)

Comment: "N2" and "C2" will add thousand separators while "0.00" won't.

Comment: Just in case you're unsure (I was), all of these ways for formatting a float value do provide rounding.

Comment: What about "00.00"? What's the point of having more than one 0 there like some people do have?

Comment: @MarcosPereira It will pad the string with zeros.  So 1.1 would turn into the string "01.10" and it would turn 22.2 into "22.20".  This may be useful for sorting or something like that.

Comment: The "0.00" format works fine, but I can't find anything about it in the official documentation (linked above) or am I blind?

Comment: @R1PFake - There is some additional information in a Page that is linked from the URL I provided. You can read more here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.int32.tostring?view=net-6.0#System_Int32_ToString_System_String_ or here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.double.tostring?view=net-6.0. Look for custom formatting.

Answer (score 61):

This is for cases that you want to use [interpolated strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/interpolated). I'm actually posting this because I'm tired of trial and error and eventually scrolling through tons of docs every time I need to format some scalar.

```
$"{1234.5678:0.00}"        "1234.57"        2 decimal places, notice that value is rounded
$"{1234.5678,10:0.00}"     "   1234.57"     right-aligned
$"{1234.5678,-10:0.00}"    "1234.57   "     left-aligned
$"{1234.5678:0.#####}"     "1234.5678"      5 optional digits after the decimal point
$"{1234.5678:0.00000}"     "1234.56780"     5 forced digits AFTER the decimal point, notice the trailing zero
$"{1234.5678:00000.00}"    "01234.57"       5 forced digits BEFORE the decimal point, notice the leading zero
$"{1234.5612:0}"           "1235"           as integer, notice that value is rounded
$"{1234.5678:F2}"          "1234.57"        standard fixed-point
$"{1234.5678:F5}"          "1234.56780"     5 digits after the decimal point, notice the trailing zero
$"{1234.5678:g2}"          "1.2e+03"        standard general with 2 meaningful digits, notice "e"
$"{1234.5678:G2}"          "1.2E+03"        standard general with 2 meaningful digits, notice "E"
$"{1234.5678:G3}"          "1.23E+03"       standard general with 3 meaningful digits
$"{1234.5678:G5}"          "1234.6"         standard general with 5 meaningful digits
$"{1234.5678:e2}"          "1.23e+003"      standard exponential with 2 digits after the decimal point, notice "e"
$"{1234.5678:E3}"          "1.235E+003"     standard exponential with 3 digits after the decimal point, notice "E"
$"{1234.5678:N2}"          "1,234.57"       standard numeric, notice the comma
$"{1234.5678:C2}"          "$1,234.57"      standard currency, notice the dollar sign
$"{1234.5678:P2}"          "123,456.78 %"   standard percent, notice that value is multiplied by 100
$"{1234.5678:2}"           "2"              :)
```

**Performance Warning**

Interpolated strings are slow. In my experience this is the order (fast to slow):

1. `value.ToString(format)+" blah blah"`
2. `string.Format("{0:format} blah blah", value)`
3. `$"{value:format} blah blah"`

Answer (score 55):

The first thing you need to do is use the `decimal` type instead of `float` for the prices. Using `float` is absolutely unacceptable for that because it cannot accurately represent most decimal fractions.

Once you have done that, [`Decimal.Round()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.decimal.round%28v=VS.80%29.aspx) can be used to round to 2 places.

Comment: Calling float "absolutelty unacceptable" here is a bit overdramatic, but the idea of using the Decimal class is certainly good.

Comment: Good point. If only op asked for advice on variable types

Comment: It might be abolsutely unacceptable, but my hands are bound here. I literally cannot change the method. It accepts floats and there is no method overloading.

Answer (score 37):

`String.Format("{0:#,###.##}", value)`

A more complex example from [String Formatting in C#](http://blog.stevex.net/string-formatting-in-csharp/):

> `String.Format("{0:$#,##0.00;($#,##0.00);Zero}", value);`
>
> This will output “$1,240.00″ if passed 1243.50. It will output the same format but in parentheses if the number is negative, and will output the string “Zero” if the number is zero.

Answer (score 35):

I believe:

```
String.Format("{0:0.00}",Sale);
```

Should do it.

See Link
[String Format Examples C#](http://www.csharp-examples.net/string-format-double/)

Answer (score 7):

As already mentioned, you will need to use a formatted result; which is all done through the `Write()`, `WriteLine()`, `Format()`, and `ToString()` methods.

What has not been mentioned is the **Fixed-point Format** which allows for a specified number of decimal places. It uses an 'F' and the number following the 'F' is the number of decimal places outputted, as shown in the examples.

```
Console.WriteLine("{0:F2}", 12);    // 12.00 - two decimal places
Console.WriteLine("{0:F0}", 12.3);  // 12 - ommiting fractions
```

Answer (score 7):

I like to use

```
$"{value:0.##}
```

It displays decimals optionally if there is some value.

Examples:

```
$"{50.255:0.##} //50,25
$"{50.2:0.##}   //50,2
$"{50.00:0.##}  //50
```

Answer (score 5):

```
string outString= number.ToString("####0.00");
```

Comment: There are different between "0" and "#" in custom format. "0": Replaces the zero with the corresponding digit if one is present; otherwise, zero appears in the result string. "#": Replaces the "#" symbol with the corresponding digit if one is present; otherwise, no digit appears in the result string. [Reference](https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-format-floating-point-numbers-in-C)

Answer (score 0):

```
    private float LimitDecimalPlace(double number,int limitPlace)
    {
        float result = 0;
        string sNumber = number.ToString();
        int decimalIndex = sNumber.IndexOf(".");
        if (decimalIndex != -1)
        {
            sNumber = sNumber.Remove(decimalIndex + limitPlace + 1);
        }
       
        result = float.Parse(sNumber);
        return result;
    }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).