# Selecting an Item or column in a Repeater and changing the Data

Tags: c#, asp.net, xaml, visual-studio-2012

I am trying to change the data in my repeater
so far I am cycling through each row by Item and AlternatingItem
but I want change the values in the last column
so that the value is to two decimal places. I have a basic
Connection to a stored procedure which populates the repeater
code below:

connection to the stored procedure:

```
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("Stored Procedure", conn);
    da.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    da.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Admin", "ALL"));
    DataSet dataset = new DataSet();
    da.Fill(dataset);
    rptItems.DataSource = dataset.Tables[0];
    rptItems.DataBind();
```

Code for the ItemDataBound method:

```
    protected void rptconsole_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType  ==ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
        {
           //Code should go here which changes the values of the last column
           //To two decimal places
        }
    }
```

html/XAML code to populate the repeater:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rptconsole" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="rptconsole_ItemDataBound">

       <HeaderTemplate>

            <table id="tablework">

                <th>Console</th>
                <th>Color</th>
                <th>Features</th>
                <th>Description</th>
                <th>price</th>

</HeaderTemplate>
        <ItemTemplate>

            <tr>
                <td align="center"><%# Eval("[ConsoleType]") %></td>
                <td align="center"><%# Eval("[color]") %></td>
                <td align="center"><%# Eval("[features]") %></td>
                <td align="center"><%# Eval("[desc]") %></td>
                <td align="center"><%# Eval("[price]") %></td>
            </tr>


        </ItemTemplate>
        <AlternatingItemTemplate>

            <tr>
        <td align="center"><%# Eval("[ConsoleType]") %></td>
                <td align="center"><%# Eval("[color]") %></td>
                <td align="center"><%# Eval("[features]") %></td>
                <td align="center"><%# Eval("[desc]") %></td>
                <td align="center"><%# Eval("[price]") %></td>
            </tr>
        </AlternatingItemTemplate>

        <FooterTemplate>
            </table>
        </FooterTemplate> 
    </asp:Repeater>
```

Comment: Do you want to round of the value of 'price' column?

Comment: actually I want to have it to two decimal places at the moment its a number such as 12.445665764433

Comment: I post a answer and just update it, Please check

Comment: I am getting an error underneath ("0.00") which says ... Argument type string is not assignable to parameter type System.IFormatProvider

Comment: I update the answer, please check gain. use this `Convert.ToDecimal(tdPrice.InnerText).ToString("C2");`

Comment: I am getting the following error ... Object reference not set to an instance of an object.Object reference not set to an instance of an object. Underneath that line(previous comment)

Comment: did you change the html code as i did?

Comment: yes I changed the html code

Comment: on which line you getting the error `HtmlTableCell tdPrice = e.Item.FindControl("price") as HtmlTableCell;`  or after it?

Comment: it says Input string was not in a correct format.

Answer (score 0):

change HTML like i did, I made the td to runat server

```
   <HeaderTemplate>

        <table id="tablework">

            <th>Console</th>
            <th>Color</th>
            <th>Features</th>
            <th>Description</th>
            <th>price</th>
```

```
        <tr>
            <td align="center"><%# Eval("[ConsoleType]") %></td>
            <td align="center"><%# Eval("[color]") %></td>
            <td align="center"><%# Eval("[features]") %></td>
            <td align="center"><%# Eval("[desc]") %></td>
            <td  runat="server" id="price" align="center"><%# Eval("[price]") %></td>
        </tr>


    </ItemTemplate>
    <AlternatingItemTemplate>

        <tr>
    <td align="center"><%# Eval("[ConsoleType]") %></td>
            <td align="center"><%# Eval("[color]") %></td>
            <td align="center"><%# Eval("[features]") %></td>
            <td align="center"><%# Eval("[desc]") %></td>
            <td  runat="server" id="price" align="center"><%# Eval("[price]") %></td>
        </tr>
    </AlternatingItemTemplate>

    <FooterTemplate>
        </table>
    </FooterTemplate> 
</asp:Repeater>
```

After that you need to find that td at server side and need to change the value like i did below

```
protected void rptconsole_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType  ==ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
        {
           HtmlTableCell tdPrice = e.Item.FindControl("price") as HtmlTableCell;    
           tdPrice.InnerText = Convert.ToDecimal(tdPrice.InnerText).ToString("C2"); //2dp Number or any value you want
        }
    }
```

ref: [Formatting a float to 2 decimal places](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6356351/formatting-a-float-to-2-decimal-places)

Comment: thanks for the response but the tdPrice.InnerText=.... I don't want to change it by hard code I want to change the number which is already in that column to two decimal places

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use OnItemDataBound event for that at all.

You can do it like this in ASP markup:

```
...
<td  runat="server" id="price" align="center"><%# String.Format("{0:F2}", Eval("[price]")) %></td>
...
```

Or if you want to use .NET currency formatting:

```
...
<td  runat="server" id="price" align="center"><%# String.Format("{0:C}", Eval("[price]")) %></td>
...
```

Check this article for more specific information about .NET Standard Numeric Format String: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)