# Input String was not in correct format error C# ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2012

I am getting the following error on my code : "Input String was not in a correct format". on the line following line:

```
Convert.ToDecimal(tdprice.InnerText).ToString("##.###");
```

In the code block:

```
protected void rptConsole_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
        {
            HtmlTableCell tdprice = e.Item.FindControl("price") as HtmlTableCell;
            tdprice.InnerText = Convert.ToDecimal(tdprice.InnerText).ToString("##.###");
        }
    }
```

To get a full understanding of what I am trying to do please visit the following link [Selecting an Item or column in a Repeater and changing the Data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24204529/selecting-an-item-or-column-in-a-repeater-and-changing-the-data)

Comment: What is the value of your `tdprice.InnerText` exactly and what is your `CurrentCulture`?

Comment: the current value is for example 5.33432 float

Comment: And your `CurrentCulture` is..?

Comment: Have you used the debugger, is the value of InnerText really 5.33432? Do you use dot as decimal separator?

Comment: GB, but the date is entered like yyyy/mm/dd

Comment: The value is coming from a stored procedure and in that stored procedure it is a float

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use OnItemDataBound event for that at all.

You can do it like this in ASP markup:

```
...
<td align="center"><%# String.Format("{0:F2}", Eval("[price]")) %></td>
...
```

Or if you want to use .NET currency formatting:

```
...
<td align="center"><%# String.Format("{0:C}", Eval("[price]")) %></td>
...
```

Check this article for more specific information about .NET Standard Numeric Format String: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

[`Convert.ToDecimal(string)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hf9z3s65%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method uses [`Decimal.Parse(string, CurrentCulture)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t7xswkc6%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) explicitly. Here how it's [implemented](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/convert.cs#5c25d4c3f9036374);

```
public static decimal ToDecimal(String value)
{
    if (value == null)
        return 0m;
    return Decimal.Parse(value, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
}
```

And `Decimal.Parse(string, CurrentCulture)` method [implemented](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/decimal.cs#3c8be4ea6302d5a4) as;

```
public static Decimal Parse(String s, IFormatProvider provider)
{
    return Number.ParseDecimal(s, NumberStyles.Number, NumberFormatInfo.GetInstance(provider));
}
```

As you can see, it uses [`NumberStyles.Number`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Globalization.NumberStyles.aspx) enumeration. This is a composite style which can contains;

- Leading and trailing white spaces (where [`Char.IsWhiteSpace`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.char.iswhitespace.aspx) returns `true`)
- Leading and trailing signs (`CurrentCulture`'s [`PositiveSign`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberformatinfo.positivesign.aspx) and [`NegativeSign`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberformatinfo.negativesign.aspx))
- Decimal separator (`CurrentCulture`'s [`NumberDecimalSeparator`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberformatinfo.numberdecimalseparator.aspx) property)
- Thousands separator (`CurrentCulture`'s [`NumberGroupSeparator`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberformatinfo.numbergroupseparator.aspx) property)

Since you said your method fails with `5.33432` value, most probably your `CurrentCulture`'s [`NumberDecimalSeparator`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberformatinfo.numberdecimalseparator.aspx) property is not `.`

You can use [`.Clone()` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.clone%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for create a copy [`CultureInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.aspx) based on your `CurrentCulture` and set this property to `.`