# Why does Math.Round(106.8, 2, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero) return 106.8 and not 106.80?

Tags: c#

I need the number returned to have exactly 2 decimal points but I can't seem to get this to work.

Is this something built into `C#`?

I also tried setting the number to a double and a decimal and I get the same answer both times.

```
price = Math.Round(106.8, 2, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero);
```

Comment: If this is for display purposes use `price.ToString('0.00')`. See [Formatting a float to 2 decimal places](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6356351/formatting-a-float-to-2-decimal-places)

Comment: Simply because numeric types don't store useless trailing/front zeroes. Would be a big waste of space to keep them. Simply pad your numbers when you store them as a string.

Comment: What you see is the representation of the value. Mathematically, 106.8 and 106.80 (or 106.800000) is exactly the same value and `decimal` type stores value not the representation of it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Floating-point values `106.8d` and `106.80d` are totally the same. Use `.ToString()` or `string.Format()` to represent them as strings with desired formatting.

Comment: Thank you for that. I had thought I was going crazy for it not working but I see that this makes sense