# Using SQL read for export to txt, convert float to specific view

Tags: c#

I'm using this code for exporting from my SQL Server to a `.txt` file. When I use a column which is typed as float, I want to get specific view.

So this let's say that my column value is '1', I want to get a result of `1.000`, or if it is 1.1, I want the result to be `1.100`. Also if I have `0.5`, the desired result is `0.500`.

Here is my code:

```
SqlDataReader read = cmd.ExecuteReader();

using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(@"C:\xxx.txt"))
{
    while (read.Read())
    {
        sw.Write(read["Quantity"].ToString());
    }
}
```

I have already tried to convert to `demical` but I get same result. Example if my column is 1, I get result 1.

I have also use padright but it doesn't take my separator.

```
  sw.Write(read["Quantity"].ToString().PadRight(4,'0'));
```

Comment: [start here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ek5h49e6(v=vs.110).aspx). Either specify a format string in the call to `ToString()`, or set the `FormatProvider` property of the `StreamWriter`.

Comment: I tried this but i get same result    Double d = Double.Parse(read["Quantity"].ToString());
                        sw.Write(d);

Comment: This might help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6356351/formatting-a-float-to-2-decimal-places

Comment: Is different method for streamwriter?

Comment: Please give me an example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
String.Format("{0:0.000}", 0.5);
```

just put your number at 0.5

```
SqlDataReader read = cmd.ExecuteReader();
using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(@"C:\xxx.txt"))
{
    while (read.Read())
    {
        sw.Write(String.Format("{0:0.000}", double.Parse(read["Quantity"].ToString())));
    }
}
```