# how to remove the characters after the 2 decimal values in C#

Tags: c#

I want to remove the characters after 2 decimal values. while I'm formatting not getting any changes in the value. I don't want convert it to double and then string due to performance issue may arise.

```
data type is Float in the database
value -172.209
Exp op - 172.20
```

code

```
  string max_demand = dt_max_demand.Rows[0][0].ToString();
  max_demand= String.Format("{0:0.0#}", max_demand);
```

Comment: Coverting to `Decimal` and back to `string` is very fast.

Comment: What data type has your column `dt_max_demand.Rows[0][0]`?

Comment: dt_max_demand.Rows[0][0] is float value

Comment: sooo why are you converting it to string in the first place, instead of using the mighty number formatting options of string.format? there is absolutly _no_ point in doing so whatsoever.

Comment: Is the data type a numeric type? If so just use the "n2" format

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Formatting a float to 2 decimal places](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6356351/formatting-a-float-to-2-decimal-places)

Comment: that is not working for me @ChrᴉzsupportsMonica
dt_max_demand.Rows[0][0].ToString("n2");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could search for the last '.' character in your string and then cut it after 2 more chars but it would be way more efficient and easier to format it using `$"{dt_max_demand.Rows[0][0]:F2}"`, assuming `dt_max_demand.Rows[0][0]` has a numeric type before you cast it to a string.

```
  string max_demand = $"{dt_max_demand.Rows[0][0]:F2}";
```