# Output two numbers after comma with CultureInfo

Tags: c#

Can someone provide the simple way to output float value in such format in C#: 
*dddddd,dd* - exactly **two digits** after **comma**

I tried this:

```
number.ToString(CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("uk-UA"));
```

but I don't know how to print two digits after a comma (even if there will be only ",00").

Optionally:
I also need to print numbers in this format:
*d,ddd,ddd.dd*

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6951335/using-string-format-to-show-decimal-up-to-2-places-or-simple-integer - Is this of any help?

Comment: @Maritim, the problem is that they are using the dot separator and I need a comma.

Comment: @Dark_Phoenix Do you have the correct culture name? `uk-UA       uk-UA       Ukrainian (Ukraine)`

Comment: @LeeTaylor, I got the info here: https://www.csharp-examples.net/culture-names/
It also replaces a dot with a comma correctly.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58733847/933198

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use this format string: `"0.00"`.

```cs
using System.Globalization;

var data = new[] {0, 1, 1.2, 1.234, 1.2345, 123456789.123123 };
var nfi = (NumberFormatInfo)CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.NumberFormat.Clone();
nfi.NumberGroupSeparator = ",";

foreach (var item in data)
{
    // first format
    Console.Write(item.ToString("0.00", CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("uk-UA"))+"\t");

    // second optional question
    Console.WriteLine(item.ToString("#,0.00", nfi));
}
```

Output:

```
0,00
1,00
1,20
1,23
1,23
123,12
```