# toFixed function in c#

Tags: c#, javascript

in Javascript, the toFixed() method formats a number to use a specified number of trailing decimals.
[Here is toFixed method in javascript](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_tofixed.asp)

How can i write a same method in c#?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Use the various String.Format() patterns.

For example:

```
int someNumber = 20;
string strNumber = someNumber.ToString("N2");
```

Would produce 20.00. (2 decimal places because N2 was specified).

[Standard Numeric Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx) gives a lot of information on the various format strings for numbers, along with some examples.

Comment: Alternatively, use `decimalVar.ToString ("#.##");` as recommended [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/164926/c-sharp-how-do-i-round-a-decimal-value-to-2-decimal-places-for-output-on-a-pa).

Comment: @meepzh - That's a valid alternative, but it's worth noting some of the caveats in the comments.

Comment: @Tim, how to do if I need to multiply after converting into #.##?

Comment: @ShuhratjanNizamov - You multiply the values and *then* convert into the format you want.  You can't really do math on strings :)

Answer (score 6):

You could make an extension method like this:

```
using System;

namespace toFixedExample
{
    public static class MyExtensionMethods
    {
        public static string toFixed(this double number, uint decimals)
        {
            return number.ToString("N" + decimals);
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            double d = 465.974;
            var a = d.toFixed(2);
            var b = d.toFixed(4);
            var c = d.toFixed(10);
        }
    }
}
```

will result in:
a: "465.97", b: "465.9740", c: "465.9740000000"

Answer (score 0):

```
using System;

namespace ClassLibrary1
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static string ToFixed(decimal value, uint decimals)
        {
            var step = Convert.ToDecimal(Math.Pow(10, decimals));
            return (Math.Truncate((value) * step) / step).ToString();
        }
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ToFixed(3.154567M, 2));
            Console.WriteLine(ToFixed(3.154567M, 3));
            Console.WriteLine(ToFixed(3.154567M, 4));
            Console.WriteLine(ToFixed(3.154567M, 5));
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

will result in:
3,15 |
3,154 |
3,1545 |
3,15456 |