# How to round to two decimal places in a string?

Tags: c#, asp.net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [c# - How do I round a decimal value to 2 decimal places (for output on a page)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/164926/c-sharp-how-do-i-round-a-decimal-value-to-2-decimal-places-for-output-on-a-pa)

```
string strTemp = "0.51667308807373";
```

convert to decimal by rounding of two decimal places.

Comment: What have you tried? What didn't work? Please post your code and explain where you are having difficulties.

Comment: Do you want the number stored to be rounded or do you just want to round it when you display? ie should the decimal variable be storing "0.51667308807373" and showing "0.52" or should it be storing "0.52"?

Comment: @Binary Worrier: this question is more about parsing than formatting I think...

Answer (score 43, accepted):

```
Math.Round(Convert.ToDecimal(strTemp), 2);
```

Answer (score 20):

First convert string to decimal (Using Decimal.Parse or Decimal.TryParse).

```
decimal d = Decimal.Parse("123.45678");
```

Then round the decimal value using Round(d, m) where d is your number, m is the number of 
decimals, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6be1edhb.aspx

```
decimal rounded = Decimal.Round(d, 2);
```

If you only want to round for presentation, you can skip rounding to a decimal and instead simply round the value in output:

```
string.Format("{0:0.00}", 123.45678m);
```

Answer (score 6):

Convert the value to a floating point number, then round it:

```
double temp = Double.Parse(strTemp, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
temp = Math.Round(temp, 2);
```

Alternatively, if you want the result as a string, just parse it and format it to two decimal places:

```
double temp = Double.Parse(strTemp, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
string result = temp.ToString("N2", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Note: The `CultureInfo` object is so that the methods will always use a period as decimal separator, regardless of the local culture settings.

Answer (score 0):

```
var roundedTemp = Math.Round(decimal.Parse(strTemp), 2);
```

You might want to check to ensure the string is always a decimal first but think this is the essence of it.

Comment: Since when does `Math.Round` take a string parameter?

Comment: i'd taken a quick second take before your comment, it's hardly a paradigm leap to parse the string ;)

Comment: It's hardly a good answer if it doesn't even compile. Do you think the OP would have been able to make the leap by himself?

Comment: and edited answer before i'd seen your comment and all

Comment: Its not a paradigm leap but it is a core part of the correct answer. :)

Comment: @Chris you're not wrong and I should be more considered before firing in a quick answer.  think Oded had a point asking for more specifics on the question and on what the OP was looking for.

Comment: @dove: indeed. Anyway, you have a +1 from me now since your answer is now correct and it feels mean for you to be on a -1 due to an itchy trigger finger. :)

Comment: i need to be briefed...Is it work or fails?

Comment: @Chris ta, and think i'll pass on the magnanimity and +1 Anders.  lesson learnt

Answer (score 0):

you can use info from this link http://www.csharp-examples.net/string-format-double/ for the double value, use double.parse api

Answer (score 0):

**You can use Number format Info. Something like**

```
NumberFormatInfo nfi = new CultureInfo("en-US", false).NumberFormat;


double myInt = 0.51667308807373;

// Displays the same value with four decimal digits.
nfi.NumberDecimalDigits = 2;
Console.WriteLine(myInt.ToString("N", nfi));
Console.ReadKey();
```