# Decimal rounding not always working correctly

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I'm using `Decimal`s in VB.NET to hold values for currency. It is possible on my website to add a discount to an item, which is inputted into a text box and then the value is retrieved in the code-behind.

```
Dim discountValue As Decimal = 0
discountValue = Decimal.Round(Convert.ToDecimal(txtDiscount.Text), 2)
lblDiscount.Text = "£" & discountValue.ToString()
```

However, when I [view the label](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p2LOP.png) after adding the discount, it is not rounded to 2 decimal points.

Is there any reason this is not working? What am I doing wrong in this approach?

Note: I'm using ASP.NET VB.NET and the page is wrapped inside an UpdatePanel.

Comment: Why not [letting `String.Format` round it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7076918/107625) for you? E.g. `String.Format("{0:0.00}", discountValue);` or `discountValue.ToString("0.00")`.

Comment: Have you tried putting a break point to see where the error is? I copy/pasted your code in a console application and it's working. What is the value of txtDiscount.Text ?

Comment: @UweKeim I didn't even think of that!! It works now, thank you :)

Comment: @MorganLane if String.Format worked but ToString didn't, then the rounding setting is in your culture information, you should check the value of CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalDigits

Comment: @the_lotus Will take a look into that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because ToString() just formats it without the decimal points if the number is `*.00`

Change this line:

```
lblDiscount.Text = "£" & discountValue.ToString("N2")
```

Comment: Or `lblDiscount.Text = discountValue.ToString("C2")` to automatically use the currency symbol for the current culture.

Comment: @Blackwood Yeah, even better, depending on the needs of the OP.

Comment: I like this way more, saves me having to worry about the currency symbol in the future.

Comment: @MorganLane Now I think about it. `lblDiscount.Text = discountValue.ToString("C")` should automatically use the appropriate number of decimal places for the current culture (2 in the case of UK and US).