# How can I use string.Format() to truncate instead of round?

Tags: c#, rounding, string.format

I would like to apply `string.Format()` in such a way that it performs truncation instead of rounding. For example

```
string.Format("##", 46.5); // output is 47, but I want 46
string.Format("##.#", 46.55); // output is 46.6, but I want 46.5
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/164926/c-sharp-how-do-i-round-a-decimal-value-to-2-decimal-places-for-output-on-a-pa

Answer (score 0):

Use `Math.Truncate` to truncate before formatting for output

Comment: That's "Truncate" (with an n), btw

Comment: That's not what he wants 46.55 to be 46.5, I think. Math.Truncate would return 46.

Comment: var v = Math.Truncate(46.5);
v.ToString("##.#") // gives 46

Comment: This answer does not use a format strings to get the desired result.