# format listview column to 2 decimal places

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I have this code , i have search in the site how to format a column

```
listView2.Items.Clear();
listView2.GridLines = true;
        for (int i = 0; i < miraxy.Rows.Count; i++) 
            {
                DataRow drow = miraxy.Rows[i];

                if (drow.RowState != DataRowState.Deleted)
                {
                    ListViewItem lvi = new ListViewItem(drow["CFOP"].ToString());
                    lvi.SubItems.Add(drow["Tnota"].ToString());
                    lvi.SubItems.Add(drow["Valor"].ToString());
                    listView2.Items.Add(lvi);
                }
            }
```

i need to format the column "Valor" to 123.2456.789,2345 i have try with this code but don work .i need format to 2 decimal places.

```
   lvi.SubItems.Add( string.Format( "{0:000,000.00}",drow["Valor"].ToString()));
```

With this line :

```
     lvi.SubItems.Add( string.Format( "{0:000,000.00}", Convert.ToDecimal (drow["Valor"])));
```

i have this result  :
                       1.419.192,67
                          001.528,41   how i need to write to kill the left zeros??

Thanks by any help

Comment: `123.2456.789,23` Why two decimals?

Comment: Can you make a proper example?

Comment: What do you mean by "but don work"?  Do you get an error?  Badly formatted data?

Comment: did you try this or another similar question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/164926/c-sharp-how-do-i-round-a-decimal-value-to-2-decimal-places-for-output-on-a-pa

Comment: You can't format a string thus - you need to pass `String.Format` a numerical variable as the second argument (rather than a string, as would be returned by the `ToString` function) for this to work as you expect.

Comment: i have modified this to numerical see above

Answer (score 0):

Use this format string:

```
string.Format("{0:#,##0.00}", Convert.ToDecimal(drow["Valor"]))
```

The `#`'s (as opposite to `0`) make that part of format used only, when the number is large enough.