# How to round decimal values using Math.Round but keep trailing zeros

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, math, decimal

In my application certain fields contain decimal numbers. And it is possible to enter only 2 decimal points. After doing some calculations, the result is displayed, and the answer should also contain 2 decimal points. For that I used the code below:-

```
obj.Revenue = 0.00m;

obj.Revenue = Math.Round(Convert.ToDecimal(obj.Revenue), 2);
```

**[EDIT]**

Inside view:-

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Revenue, new { @id = "txtRevenue", @readonly = "readonly", @class = "decimalField" })
```

So that 300.00 should be displayed as answer. But I got 300. How can I solve this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/164926/c-sharp-how-do-i-round-a-decimal-value-to-2-decimal-places-for-output-on-a-pa

Comment: How do you display this value in the view?

Comment: Do you really want to round Revenue, or do you simply want that value to be rounded when it is displayed?

Answer (score 0):

Use toFixed(n);

```
var d = 300.00;
alert(d.toFixed(2));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use toFixed() function

For example:

```
(12.5).toFixed(2); // 12.50
```

Comment: Got error like this:-'decimal' does not contain a definition for 'toFixed' and no extension method 'toFixed' accepting a first argument of type 'decimal' could be found

Comment: @Mizbella try this:
string test=String.Format("{0:0.00}", 300);
var convert = Convert.ToDecimal(test);

Comment: @ David Rego:-while converting to decimal .00 is lost

Comment: i try to print with convert value and shows me 300.00. 
string test=String.Format("{0:0.00}", 300); 
var convert = Convert.ToDecimal(test);Console.WriteLine(convert);

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Revenue, new {value = Model.Revenue.ToString("#.##"), @id = "txtRevenue", @readonly = "readonly", @class = "decimalField" })
```

Comment: It will not work because templates can be used with properties with both get and set accessors.

Comment: I just updated this...I wasn't using the right format for changing the  value.

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement get accessor for the model.Revenue property this way:

```
get{ return _revenue.ToString("#.##"); }
```

Answer (score 0):

I know its too late to answer this question but it may help other.

You can simply write this line in your model where you have declared the property. `[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:0.###}")]`

here is the practical example which i used in my code.

```
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:0.##}")]
    public Decimal CreditLimit { get; set; }
```

this will set your value up to two decimal.

> e.g.
>   3.3333333 => 3.33