# how to drop decimals after 3rd decimal

Tags: c#

I have a UI control which is based on a double instead of an decimal.

When it should return a value of 0.001 it returns a value of 0.00100000004749745

How do I convert this to a decimal with the correct value of 0.001?

Note that I am not trying to format it as a string, just get the correct value.

Comment: Your best bet is to start using decimal when you care about that precision. Powers of ten do not have simple representations in base-2. All of the conversions and rounding will result in error at some point.

Comment: I agree, but the control is based on a double and I cannot rewrite the control. Thus I am converting the number before actually using it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

just  use [`Math.Round Method (Decimal, Int32)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zy06z30k%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
            double d = 0.00100000004749745;
            double ma = Math.Round(d, 3);  
            //if you want it as a string 
            string s = ma.ToString();
```

Comment: I think you need to add the ToString into there so only 3 dps are shown

Answer (score 1):

```
double d= 0.00100000004749745;
String s=d.ToString("N3");    //gives you 0.001
decimal dd=Convert.ToDecimal(s);//converts double value 0.001 into decimal
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
double d= yourNum;
String s=d.ToString("0.00");
```

Comment: `"0.000"` then :)
And convert back to `double`. Which is pretty inefficient.

Comment: in question he is not asking for rounding he wants to get number upto two decimal places.

Answer (score 0):

You're experiencing the fact that `0.1` cannot be stored *exactly* in a `double`.

If you just want to *display* the result in 3 decimals and not worry about the floating-point error just use:

```
string s = dec.ToString("0.000");
```

Answer (score 0):

you can find a similar question already answered here using the String Format :

[c# - How do I round a decimal value to 2 decimal places (for output on a page)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/164926/c-sharp-how-do-i-round-a-decimal-value-to-2-decimal-places-for-output-on-a-pa)

This can be a simple way to solve your problem using :

```
decimalVar.ToString ("#.###");
```

For more complex purposes this can be used if you want to keep working with a decimal value :

```
decimal.Round(yourValue, 3, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero);
```