# Masked Textbox Format

Tags: c#, .net, formatting, maskedtextbox

I would like my masked to display `2.00` when I input `2`.
My current code is

```
txtBox.Mask = "##0.00";
```

OUTPUT:

```
2 .
```

Is there anything I'm doing wrong?

Comment: What do you mean by "output"? How do you obtain that result?

Comment: Look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/164926/c-sharp-how-do-i-round-a-decimal-value-to-2-decimal-places-for-output-on-a-pa

Comment: OUTPUT is the current result I am getting. What I would like to get as a result when I enter **2** is **2.00**