# c# Decimal issues

Tags: c#, decimal

Code first.

```
taxRateDecimal = 0.0765;
if (taxRateDecimal.ToString().Split('.').Length == 2)
{
    outPut =  taxRateDecimal.ToString().Split('.')[1].Substring(0, 4);
    ReportParameters.Add("TaxRateAsDecimal", "." + outPut); 
}
```

As you can see in the substring I have to hard code my length of 4.
Desired results .0765 as a string.

Here are some scenarios I have gone through.

I have a percent of 7.65.
I want to convert this to decimal, when doing so I do 7.65 / 100.
this gives me 0.0765, but I want just .0765.
If I take 0.0765 and use a split on "." and use length ect..
I actually get for the array [1] a length of 6 and a value of 076500.
Again I only want .0765 or just 0765 and I can add the dot.

Any other ideas that I have not tried?
This will eventually need to be a string since I am passing it in as a prama into SSRS.

Comment: Are you just trying to format a decimal into a string?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/164926/c-sharp-how-do-i-round-a-decimal-value-to-2-decimal-places-for-output-on-a-pa its not exactly what you want but it should be of help.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to use a format to create the string:

```
var taxRateDecimal = 0.0765D;
var reportParameter = taxRateDecimal.ToString(".0000", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

The resulting `reportParameter` is `.0765`.

Other results for that format are:

```
0D       ->  .0000
1D       -> 1.0000
1.23456D -> 1.2346
```

You have to use `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` to be sure that the decimal separator is a dot. Otherwise the current culture (which is the default) might specify a comma as the decimal separator.

Answer (score 1):

`string.Format` will handle this easily.

```
double taxRateDecimal = 1.0765;
string formattedResult = string.Format("{0:.0000}", taxRateDecimal % 1);

Console.WriteLine(formattedResult);  // .0765
```