# Concat two integers

Tags: c#, integer

I am using MVC 4. I've got an MVC Form two fields **AmtInDollars & AmtInCents**. I want to concatenate the two. Eg

```
var tempDollarAmt = AmtInDollars + "" + AmtInCents;
```

Example

- Input: 100 in dollars
- Input: 00 in cents
- Output: 1000 // missing 1 zero due to input being 00.
- Desired Output: 10000.

I realized that if the AmtInCents is between 0 and 9 it ingnores the 0. So if I type 09 the output is 9 not 09.

I have tried doing an if statement below and still no luck.

```
if(Products.AmtInCents < 10)
                {
                    var tempCents = 0;
                    Products.AmtInCents = 00;
                }
```

Here my class

```
public decimal? AmtInDollars { get; set; }
public decimal? AmtInCents { get; set; }
```

How can I do this?

Comment: This code looks like c#. Is this c#?

Comment: you want "zero padding"

Comment: Try this.. `var tempDollarAmt = AmtInDollars.ToString() + AmtInCents.ToString();`

Comment: possible duplicate of [c# - How do I round a decimal value to 2 decimal places (for output on a page)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/164926/c-sharp-how-do-i-round-a-decimal-value-to-2-decimal-places-for-output-on-a-pa)

Comment: Why not directly using `string` type? what is the reason and why it has to be `decimal?`?

Comment: You should not use the names `AmtInDollars` and `AmountInCents`. I would assume that both variables would hold the entire amount rather than each holding a portion of the total. I would recommend that you use `Dollars` and `Cents` since the actual amount is them combined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//Input: 100 in dollars
int dollars = 100;
//Input: 00 in cents
int cents = 0;

//OutPut: 1000 // missing 1 zero due to input being 00.
int output = dollars * 100 + cents;
```

Comment: Thank you everyone. I really appreciate your help!

Answer (score 3):

you should use string.format to force padding when formating number

```
var tempDollarAmt = String.Format("{0}.{1:00}",AmtInDollars ,AmtInCents);
```

Comment: I get an error **Input string was not in a correct format.** when trying to save it.

Comment: I should've mention before the error above I got **cannot implicitly convert string to decimal**.  Then I did  `Convert.ToInt32(tempDollarAmt)`   and got the **Input string was not in a correct format.** error.