# Response from API not showing decimal 0.000000

Tags: c#, .net, system.text.json

I'm new in dotNet development and trying to create an API with response  having  decimals. I'm expecting that the API will show `0.000000` but instead only shows `0`.

This is the data from my database

[image: database screenshot]

```
public class InvAmt
    {
        public double buyWsAmount { get; set; }
        public double buyRetAmount { get; set; }
        public double sellWsAmount { get; set; }
        public double sellRetAmount { get; set; }
    }
```

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<ActionResult<List<InvAmt>>> GetInvAmt()
 {
   var connString = _config.GetConnectionString("Mysqlconn");

   using (IDbConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(connString))
    {
      string sql = $@"SELECT pa.buy_ws_amount AS buyWsAmount, pa.buy_retail_amount AS buyRetAmount, pa.sell_ws_amount AS sellWsAmount, pa.sell_retail_amount AS sellRetAmount FROM product_amount pa;";

      var res = await conn.QueryAsync<ProductCategory>(sql, null);
      return res.ToList();
     }
  }
```

API response

```
[
  {
    "id": 1
    "buyWsAmount": 1300,
    "buyRetAmount": 26,
    "sellWsAmount": 1800,
    "sellRetAmount": 36.000001,
  },
  {
    "id": 52
    "buyWsAmount": 0,
    "buyRetAmount": 0,
    "sellWsAmount": 0,
    "sellRetAmount": 0,
  }
]
```

Comment: AFAIK this isn't supported natively with System.Text.Json. You'll have to write a custom converter to handle this. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34569851/2084984) sums it up nicely.

Comment: It's worth noting, though, that this is purely cosmetic. `0` is equal to `0.00` in JSON, `0` is just a simpler representation.