# Number decimal precision with System.Text.Json

Tags: c#, system.text.json, json-serialization

How do I write (serialize) a float to JSON with fixed 2 decimals using `System.Text.Json`?

Like `{"Amount": 12.30}`.

Not like `{"Amount": 12.3}` or `{"Amount": 12.3001}` or `{"Amount": "12.30"}`.

It seems there is no decimal precision option for float (or decimal or double or whatever), in `JsonWriterOptions` or either in `JsonSerializerOptions`. Also writing own converter seems to be unclear: `Utf8JsonWriter` writer WriteWhat?

Comment: `1`, `1.0` and `1.00` are generally treated as equivalent in JSON. Is this just to make for a prettier display, or does your JSON parser really treat them as different? ([From an anonymous user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34568963/how-can-i-force-a-minimum-number-of-decimal-places-in-json-net#comment56882219_34568963))

Comment: @dbc: That decade-old question is about Newtonsoft.Json, not System.Text.Json.

Comment: You shouldn't use floating numbers for money values, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3730019/why-not-use-double-or-float-to-represent-currency

Comment: Thanks, meanwhile relevant comments, I'm API consumer, not producer. :-)

Comment: Why do you want to format data within JSON? JSON is a *data exchange* format. Formatting is mainly a *display* issue.

Comment: @MustafaÖzçetin: if you have to provide data to legacy APIs you sometimes have to adhere to such requirements, even if you know it's wrong

Answer (score 0):

Ok found it, raw converter seems to work:

```ml
type TwoDecimalsConverter() =
    inherit System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonConverter<float>()

    override _.Write(writer: System.Text.Json.Utf8JsonWriter, value, serializer) =
        writer.WriteRawValue(value.ToString "0.00")

    override _.Read(reader, typeToConvert, options) =
        failwith "Not implemented"
```

Comment: That looks like F#, not C#.

Answer (score 0):

```cs
public class JsonConverterDouble : JsonConverter<double>
{
    public override double Read(ref Utf8JsonReader reader,
        Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        return reader.GetDouble();
    }

    public override void Write(Utf8JsonWriter writer, double value,
        JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        writer.WriteRawValue(value.ToString("0.##",
            CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
    }
}
```

Converters can be used in JsonSerializerOptions, for example:

```cs
var json = JsonSerializer.Serialize(data, new JsonSerializerOptions()
{
    Converters = { new JsonConverterDouble() }
});
```

You can change the formatting "0.##" for your needs.

This sollution works, <s>but is a little slow when using CreateSpecificCulture</s> use CultureInfo.InvariantCulture for speed.